# Making a C macro substitute itself as a function call in the result?

Tags: c, macros, identifier, variadic-macros, undeclared-identifier

I have a logging macro and a function, and I would like for them to have the same name, so that when I miss the header with the macro, the program would still build (via C *implicit function* declaration).

I've tried:

```
/* Declare function. */
void logmsg(const char *fmt, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

/* Declare macro (with the same name). */
#define logmsg(fmt, ...) \
        logmsg(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

However this fails with a compilation error:

```
In file included from util.c:53:
../lib/util.h:296:13: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘do’
  296 |             do { if (1) (logmsg(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)); } while (0)
      |             ^~
util.c:248:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘logmsg’
  248 | void logmsg(const char *fmt, ...)
      |      ^~~~~~
../lib/util.h:296:59: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘while’
  296 |             do { if (1) (logmsg(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)); } while (0)
      |                                                           ^~~~~
util.c:248:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘logmsg’
  248 | void logmsg(const char *fmt, ...)
```

How can I accomplish my goal?

**EDIT:**

I've solved the issue via the *[indirect self-reference of macro identifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html#Self-Referential-Macros)* like the following:

```
void logmsg(const char *fmt, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

#define log_impl(specarg, fmt, ...) \
            logmsg(fmt,##__VA_ARGS__)

#define logmsg(fmt, ...) \
            log_impl(msg,fmt,##__VA_ARGS__)
```

The `msg` arg to `log_impl()` is rather not needed, but I've stashed the code and cannot test it to be sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with implicit declaration, which in any case has been illegal since C99.

Comment: I think your original intent is misguided. If you forget to include a header, the best result is for it to cause an error, so you can fix it by adding the `#include`.

Comment: Call the function differently and link one object without macro include but with a functon the name of the macro, that calls the differently named function. Not really nice.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://tio.run/##fU9Na8MwDL37V4jmYoc0Zbt2DAqD3jfYqWA0fySCxA6O0h3GfnvmZs3WXaaDQE9PT@@ZbWPMXFAw3WQdPIxsKdbto/gDYWoyNu9KeHKmw@TAT8EwxVBDuRPnSBa62PRjI00MI4NpMUHpe66grmsFWiNzoreJndZS@ph6ZDkkCuwruKvgXim1F4uS@FfpQ0CuM@qO8haH/TqPjIklDhVksrrC3x/kco6D@iG7YOUyfwpxk6pHkyLId@IWuHUwYu8g5KaWnIV1noJbo/6aOi26l7pdFYXWrwd9eD6@aK2EmLOX/IICyDXHlb5p6RQ2FzvzFw)

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?  I'm confused as to what exactly is in your header, what's in your source file, and where the error occurs.

Comment: @Barmar: I've often do temporary debugging runs across multiple files, adding `#include`s is tedious in such scenario…

Comment: Also note that calling a function with ellipsis (`, ...`) in the argument list without a prototype in scope is undefined behaviour.  C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6): _If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined._. You need to avoid undefined behaviour.  This applies in C90 as well as C99, C11, C18.

Answer (score 3):

You need to guard against the `logmsg` macro expanding in your declaration(s) of the `logmsg` function and in its definition.

What should work regardless of your ordering of the macro definition and your real C code referring to the `logmsg` function is always using parentheses around references to the `logmsg` function:

```
void (logmsg)(const char *fmt, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
void (logmsg)(const char *fmt, ...)
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro substitution is happening in the source file at the point the function named `logmsg` is defined.  Since this macro is only valid at the point when the function is called, you end up with a syntax error.  You need to undefine the macro at that point:

```
#undef logmsg
void logmsg(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    ...
```